# How do I execute a stored procedure in batches?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, nopcommerce

I inherited a NopCommerce project from a previous developer.
They left me with a Customer table with 350 million guest users.

I'm executing a stored procedure to delete the guest users but it's been running for 15 hours now.
DTU is constantly hitting 100% and the site is crashing.
Is there a way to run this in batches? Say 5 million records per run?

Here's the SQL:

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
    @TotalRecordsDeleted int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DeleteGuests]
    @CreatedFromUtc = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc = NULL,
    @TotalRecordsDeleted = @TotalRecordsDeleted OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecordsDeleted as N'@TotalRecordsDeleted'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: We have no idea what `DeleteGuests` is doing, or what your RDBMS is.

Comment: You need to analyse what the stored proc is doing; is it a single DELETE command, and deletes from a single table (with no cascading deletes via referential integrity)? If so, you might delete with DELETE TOP command in increments of your choosing. If the logic is more complex, then you need to revise the proc. In any case you can't simply set it to delete N rows without understanding what it does.

Comment: Sorry - should have been clearer. It's not a single table delete. Not 100% but at least two tables are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - turns out, there is a pretty obvious way of splitting up the job.
I'll post it below in case someone else runs into the same issue.

By setting a date range, you can run this in steps without bogging down the server for hours or days.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
    @TotalRecordsDeleted int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[DeleteGuests]
    @CreatedFromUtc = N'2022-04-01', -- Start date
    @CreatedToUtc = N'2022-04-15', -- End Date
    @TotalRecordsDeleted = @TotalRecordsDeleted OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalRecordsDeleted as N'@TotalRecordsDeleted'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```